# How to override the db_table in model for a 3rd-party packages?

Tags: django, model

I want to override the "db_table" in models.py for 3rd-party packages.
Therefore, the database table name could display what I need.

models.py

```py
from admin_honeypot.models import LoginAttempt as oldLoginAttempt_Model


class LoginAttempt_Model(oldLoginAttempt_Model):
    oldLoginAttempt_Model._meta.db_table = 'NEW-TABLE-NAME'
    class Meta:
        proxy = False
        app_label = 'admin_honeypot'
        db_table = 'NEW-TABLE-NAME'
```

admin.py

```py
from admin_honeypot.admin import LoginAttemptAdmin as oldLoginAttempt_Admin
from admin_honeypot.models import LoginAttempt as oldLoginAttempt_model

from .models import LoginAttempt_Model


admin.site.unregister(oldLoginAttempt_model)
@admin.register(LoginAttempt_Model)
class LoginAttempt_Admin(oldLoginAttempt_Admin):
    pass
```

then, I do

```sh
python manage.py makemigrations
```

database table name still on the old version.

Comment: May I ask why you need it?

Comment: because, there are too many tables in a same dB. If they can orderinary by names. It could be more easier to find out the table.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you, but do you sure you have a problem with table search speed? What is it expressed?